# Move to my location in an embedded google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here's the html code:

`<iframe id="map" width="450" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=z2opWYclBEHU.kj-xknPuw0_o"></iframe>
<a id="myLocation" href="#">My location</a>`

When you click on the 'myLocation' link it should go to your location on the map.
How would I do this? The map needs to be embedded/hard-coded already on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Location accepts a latitude and a longitude as comma-separated values (46.414382,10.013988). It needs to be hard coded for embedded maps.